# Python Web scraping span tags with BeautifulSoup4 for GBP prices

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping

First post so please be gentle. I am trying to web scrape with Python.

I aim to make a script that will access the page below:

"WWWzaraDOTcom/uk/en/sale/woman/dresses/view-all-c731533.html"

I should like the script to return the a.name.item, the data in "data-ecirp" where span class is "sale" and "crossOut diagonal-line" respectively.

I would like to use this script on other websites in time.

My current code below can access Zara, pull the page and manipulate in RE/BS - but I can't pull any prices after much googling of BeautifulSoup and span tags.

Regex hurt my brain a bit and I couldn't get any of the simple code examples from my book to work IRL.

- Is the answer to teach BeautifulSoup to traverse correctly
- Or to use RE to deduce the values from set strings?
- Or is there another better approach I should take. (I want to alert when things go on sale eventually..)

  ```
  import requests
  import re

  r =      requests.get(“http://www.zara.com/uk/en/sale/woman/dresses/view-all-c731533.html”)
  r.raise_for_status() 
  html = r.text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
  ```

Comment: pls post the html code you're dealing with..

Comment: Are you sure you can scrape that page?  I get `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Answer (score 4):

All the data you want is in the `product-info` tag, the url is also different as you have to first pick a region:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r =   requests.get("http://www.zara.com/ie/en/sale/woman/dresses/view-all-c731533.html?#utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zara.com%2F%3Fgo%3Dhttp%253A%2F%2Fwww.zara.com%2Fshare%2Fsale%2Fwoman%2Fdresses%2Fview-all-c731533.html")
r.raise_for_status()
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
prods = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "product-info"})
print(prods)
for p in prods:
    print(p.a.text)
    print("Old price  {}".format(p.find("span", {"class": "crossOut"})["data-ecirp"]))
    print("New price {}".format(p.find("span", {"class": "sale"})["data-ecirp"]))
```

Output:

```
ZIP-BACK TUBE DRESS
Old price  49.95  EUR
New price 29.99  EUR
SEQUINNED DRESS
Old price  69.95  EUR
New price 29.99  EUR
HALTER NECK SHIMMER THREAD DRESS
Old price  39.95  EUR
New price 25.99  EUR
CREPE SLEEVELESS DRESS
Old price  49.95  EUR
New price 29.99  EUR
OTTOMAN RIB DRESS
Old price  39.95  EUR
New price 25.99  EUR
SHORT LACE DRESS
Old price  49.95  EUR
New price 39.99  EUR
SPARKLY VELVET DRESS
Old price  49.95  EUR
New price 29.99  EUR
DRESS WITH SIDE GATHERING
Old price  19.95  EUR
New price 12.99  EUR
TUBE DRESS WITH STRAPPY BACK
Old price  59.95  EUR
New price 49.99  EUR
SKATER DRESS
Old price  49.95  EUR
New price 39.99  EUR
PARTY DRESS
Old price  49.95  EUR
New price 29.99  EUR
DOUBLE LAYER DRESS
........................
```

Storing the data in a dict might be a good idea:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(defaultdict)
for p in prods:
    k = p.a.text
    v1 = p.find("span", {"class": "crossOut"})["data-ecirp"]
    v2 = p.find("span", {"class": "sale"})["data-ecirp"]
    d[k]["new_price"] = v1
    d[k]["old_price"] = v2
    d[k]["saving"] = float(v1.split()[0]) - float(v2.split()[0])

print(d)
```

Which will give you:

```
defaultdict(<class 'collections.defaultdict'>, {'': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 11.96, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}),
 'CROCHET DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR','saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}),
 'BASIC SLEEVELESS DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '14.95  EUR', 'saving': 4.959999999999999, 'old_price': '9.99  EUR'}), 'FLORAL PRINT TUNIC': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'COMBINED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'SEQUINNED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '69.95  EUR', 'saving': 39.96000000000001, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'LONG CROCHET DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '89.95  EUR', 'saving': 39.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'STRIPED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '19.95  EUR', 'saving': 6.959999999999999, 'old_price': '12.99  EUR'}), 'HALTER NECK SHIMMER THREAD DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'V-NECK TUNIC': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'DRESS WITH ZIPS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '25.95  EUR', 'saving': 7.960000000000001, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}), 'FLOUNCE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'LONG TUNIC WITH SIDE VENTS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'FLOWING STUDIO DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '89.95  EUR', 'saving': 39.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'KNIT SWEATER WITH TAILORED HEM': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'BUTTON DETAIL DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'SUEDE EFFECT DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'FAUX LEATHER DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'POLKA DOT DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'CREPE SLEEVELESS DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'DEVORÉ VELVET DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '59.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'DENIM DRESS WITH BELT': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'LACE APPLIQUÉ DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'JACQUARD DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '19.99  EUR'}), 'PATCH PINAFORE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '45.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'EYELET DRESS WITH VELVET RIBBON': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'LONG LACE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 23.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'LONG PATCHWORK DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'MIDI CROSSOVER DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '19.99  EUR'}), 'EMBROIDERED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'LONG CREPE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'HALTER NECK DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '59.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'DRESS WITH GATHERED WAIST': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '19.99  EUR'}), 'GINGHAM CHECK TUNIC': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'JUMPSUIT WITH STRAPS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '19.99  EUR'}), 'DOUBLE LAYER DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '59.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'LACE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '19.99  EUR'}), 'MIDI PINAFORE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '19.99  EUR'}), 'LONG TUNIC': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'BANDEAU DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '25.95  EUR', 'saving': 7.960000000000001, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}), 'LINEN SHIRTDRESS BELT': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'STUDIO DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '59.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'CHECK PINAFORE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '19.99  EUR'}), 'LONG SILK STUDIO DRESS WITH LACE': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '99.95  EUR', 'saving': 49.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'BEAD EMBROIDERED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '59.95  EUR', 'saving': 29.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'DRESS WITH SIDE GATHERING': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '19.95  EUR', 'saving': 6.959999999999999, 'old_price': '12.99  EUR'}), 'DRESS WITH BACK OPENING': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 11.96, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}), 'SCHIFFLI LACE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 23.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'SPARKLY VELVET DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'STRAPPY DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'TUNIC WITH SLITS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'A-LINE PATCHWORK DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'DRESS WITH SEAM DETAILS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 11.96, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}), 'COMBINATION DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'MICRO-JACQUARD DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'PINAFORE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '19.99  EUR'}), 'JACQUARD GEMSTONE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 11.96, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}), 'VELVET DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'HOUNDSTOOTH PINAFORE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '19.99  EUR'}), 'KNIT DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '17.95  EUR', 'saving': 4.959999999999999, 'old_price': '12.99  EUR'}), 'LOOSE FIT PRINTED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '19.99  EUR'}), 'LEATHER EFFECT DRESS. CUT WORK': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '59.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'GEOMETRIC DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 11.96, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}), 'LONG DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '25.95  EUR', 'saving': 7.960000000000001, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}), 'RETRO PINAFORE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'CHECK DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'PRINTED SHIRT DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'PATTERNED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '39.99  EUR'}), 'DRESS WITH CHAIN NECKLINE': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '59.95  EUR', 'saving': 29.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'STAR PRINT DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 11.96, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}), 'DENIM DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'ROUND NECK DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '45.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'FLORAL PRINT DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'RUFFLE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'SHORT DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '25.99  EUR', 'saving': 8.0, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}), 'PRINTED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'FLARED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '59.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'DENIM PINAFORE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '45.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'ZIP-BACK TUBE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'ASYMMETRIC DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'DRAPED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'STRIPED JACQUARD DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '25.95  EUR', 'saving': 7.960000000000001, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}), 'DRESS WITH SIDE KNOT DETAIL': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '19.95  EUR', 'saving': 6.959999999999999, 'old_price': '12.99  EUR'}), 'OTTOMAN RIB DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'FLOWING TUNIC': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'METALLIC APPLIQUÉ TUNIC': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '19.99  EUR'}), 'PATCHWORK DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'PARTY DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'FRAYED MIDI DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '19.99  EUR'}), 'FLORAL DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'SKATER DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '39.99  EUR'}), 'DRESS WITH LOW-CUT BACK': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '39.99  EUR'}), 'LONG DOUBLE LAYER DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 11.96, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}), 'LONG TUBE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '59.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'FITTED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '14.95  EUR', 'saving': 4.959999999999999, 'old_price': '9.99  EUR'}), 'DRESS WITH V-NECK BACK': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '29.95  EUR', 'saving': 11.96, 'old_price': '17.99  EUR'}), 'LONG VELVET DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '89.95  EUR', 'saving': 39.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'HALTER DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'PRINTED TUNIC': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'FULL TUNIC WITH PLAITED BELT': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'STUDIO DRESS WITH LACE-UP BACK': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '69.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'DOTTED SWISS DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 23.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'SHORT LACE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '39.99  EUR'}), 'DRESS WITH FULL SKIRT': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'ASYMMETRICAL LONG DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '17.95  EUR', 'saving': 4.959999999999999, 'old_price': '12.99  EUR'}), 'STRAIGHT CUT DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'MIDI DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'PLEATED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 19.960000000000004, 'old_price': '29.99  EUR'}), 'LACE SKATER DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '39.99  EUR'}), 'TUBE DRESS WITH STRAPPY BACK': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '59.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'LONG PRINTED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '49.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '39.99  EUR'}), 'SHEER DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '59.95  EUR', 'saving': 33.96000000000001, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'}), 'A-LINE TOP': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '59.95  EUR', 'saving': 9.96, 'old_price': '49.99  EUR'}), 'RIBBED DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '17.95  EUR', 'saving': 4.959999999999999, 'old_price': '12.99  EUR'}), '"ESSENTIALS" DENIM PINAFORE DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '19.95  EUR', 'saving': 6.959999999999999, 'old_price': '12.99  EUR'}), 'PRINTED JUMPSUIT DRESS': defaultdict(None, {'new_price': '39.95  EUR', 'saving': 13.960000000000004, 'old_price': '25.99  EUR'})})
```

You might also find [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) useful if you are going to be analysing the data, if you store the data in tuples it will be easy make a DataFrame which you can save to and load from a csv.

```
data = []
for p in prods:
    k = p.a.text
    v1 = p.find("span", {"class": "crossOut"})["data-ecirp"]
    v2 = p.find("span", {"class": "sale"})["data-ecirp"]
    t = k, float(v1.split()[0]), float(v2.split()[0]), float(v1.split()[0]) - float(v2.split()[0])
    data.append(t)


import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["name", "old", "new", "saving"])
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=0)
```

Which will give you a df like:

```
                                 name    old    new  saving
0                 ZIP-BACK TUBE DRESS  49.95  29.99   19.96
1                     SEQUINNED DRESS  69.95  29.99   39.96
2    HALTER NECK SHIMMER THREAD DRESS  39.95  25.99   13.96
3              CREPE SLEEVELESS DRESS  49.95  29.99   19.96
4                   OTTOMAN RIB DRESS  39.95  25.99   13.96
5                    SHORT LACE DRESS  49.95  39.99    9.96
6                SPARKLY VELVET DRESS  49.95  29.99   19.96
7           DRESS WITH SIDE GATHERING  19.95  12.99    6.96
8        TUBE DRESS WITH STRAPPY BACK  59.95  49.99    9.96
9                        SKATER DRESS  49.95  39.99    9.96
10                        PARTY DRESS  49.95  29.99   19.96
11                 DOUBLE LAYER DRESS  29.95  17.99   11.96
12            DRESS WITH LOW-CUT BACK  49.95  39.99    9.96
13          DRESS WITH SIDE GATHERING  19.95  12.99    6.96
14                       STUDIO DRESS  79.95  49.99   29.96
15                 DOUBLE LAYER DRESS  59.95  49.99    9.96
16     STUDIO DRESS WITH LACE-UP BACK  69.95  49.99   19.96
```

And save it the data to a csv called data.csv.

To load the data and order by the biggest savings:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")


print(df.sort_values(["saving"],ascending=0))
```

Which would output:

```
                                  name    old    new  saving
134   LONG SILK STUDIO DRESS WITH LACE  99.95  49.99   49.96
1                      SEQUINNED DRESS  69.95  29.99   39.96
137                  LONG VELVET DRESS  89.95  49.99   39.96
71                FLOWING STUDIO DRESS  89.95  49.99   39.96
33                  LONG CROCHET DRESS  89.95  49.99   39.96
116                        SHEER DRESS  59.95  25.99   33.96
85           DRESS WITH CHAIN NECKLINE  59.95  29.99   29.96
132             BEAD EMBROIDERED DRESS  59.95  29.99   29.96
14                        STUDIO DRESS  79.95  49.99   29.96
......................................................
```

To add a column that should the percentage saving:

```
df["precent_saving"] = (df["old"] - df["new"]) / df["old"] * 100
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                               name    old    new  saving  precent_saving
0                 ZIP-BACK TUBE DRESS  49.95  29.99   19.96       39.959960
1                     SEQUINNED DRESS  69.95  29.99   39.96       57.126519
2    HALTER NECK SHIMMER THREAD DRESS  39.95  25.99   13.96       34.943680
3              CREPE SLEEVELESS DRESS  49.95  29.99   19.96       39.959960
4                   OTTOMAN RIB DRESS  39.95  25.99   13.96       34.943680
5                    SHORT LACE DRESS  49.95  39.99    9.96       19.939940
6                SPARKLY VELVET DRESS  49.95  29.99   19.96       39.959960
7           DRESS WITH SIDE GATHERING  19.95  12.99    6.96       34.887218
8        TUBE DRESS WITH STRAPPY BACK  59.95  49.99    9.96       16.613845
9                        SKATER DRESS  49.95  39.99    9.96       19.939940
10                        PARTY DRESS  49.95  29.99   19.96       39.959960
11                 DOUBLE LAYER DRESS  29.95  17.99   11.96       39.933222
```